# Need help getting array to work with string builder

Tags: arrays, vb.net, string, visual-studio

So I am building a stock info retrieval program, and I have a good bit of it done so far. Right now I have it return the price from the Yahoo Finance API by singling out the price in the returned API data and then shove it in a listbox with the stock symbol and price. That part works great, but I want to take it a step further now and be able to do what I want with other parts of that returned data. The normal format for the data is:

```
"<symbol>", <price>, "<date>", "<time>", etc.
```

If you take a look at my code, right now I have a Getstockinfo function that retrieves the full API output and converts each object(symbol, price, etc) into a new stringbuilder line, and then separates the lines by the commas using the ModifyLine function.

I want to now get the GetStockInfo to return an array, which would allow me to use that array as I pleased outside of that function(in eventhandlers, etc.)

ANY help would be much appreciated!

```
   Public Function GetStockInfo(ByVal pstrSymbol As String) As String
    Dim strURL As String
    Dim strApiOutput As String

    'Yahoo API
    strURL = "http://quote.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?" & _
             "s=" & pstrSymbol & _
             "&d=t" & _
             "&f=sl1d1t1c1ohgvj1pp2wern"

    strApiOutput = RequestWebData(strURL)

    'Create stringbuilder(easier to append, replace and insert data)
    Dim strReturn As New System.Text.StringBuilder
    'Seperate API output into different lines by using LineFeed
    For Each strLine As String In strApiOutput.Split(ControlChars.Lf)
        'makes sure line actually exists, if so, seperate and add to array using ModifyLine function
        If strLine.Length > 0 Then
            strReturn.Append(ModifyLIne(strLine) & Environment.NewLine)
        End If
    Next
    Return strReturn.ToString
End Function

Private Function ModifyLIne(ByVal strLine As String) As String
    Dim arrLine() As String
    'Splits lines by the commas(the normal api output is as follows: <Obj1>, <Obj2>, <Obj3>, etc
    'with Intermediary quotes here and there for certain objects such as Company Name
    arrLine = strLine.Split(","c)
    decStockPrice = CDec(arrLine(1))
    Return decStockPrice.ToString
End Function

Private Sub btnAdd_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAdd.Click
    Dim strSymbol As String = txtSymbol.Text
    lstStocks.Items.Add(strSymbol.ToUpper() & " - " & GetStockInfo(strSymbol))
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

`I want to take it a step further now and be able to do what I want with other parts of that returned data`  This will do what you want, just not how you want (arrays are old-school)

```
Class StockQuote
   Public Symbol As String
   Public Price As Decimal
   Public QuoteDate As DateTime
   ' etc 
End Class

Friend myQuotes As New List(of StockQuote)
```

Then after you get a quote and determine you want to save it (are you saving all of them?):

```
Dim SQ as New StockQuote
With SQ
    .Symbol = arrLine(0)    ' so you can pass an array or list of ticker syms
    .Price = Convert.ToDecimal(arrLine(1))
    ' not much sense saving Time and Date as sep items
    ' if you are getting multiple quotes for a day (vs ending)
    .QuoteDate = combine arrline(2) and arrLine(3) ?
    etc
 End SQ
 myQuotes.Add(SQ)
```

Now, `myQuotes` will have a list of all the quotes for all the symbols.  Get them like you populated it: `txtSym.Text = myQuotes(N).Symbol`